# Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear transformation that has eigenvalues $\lambda = -1,0,2$. Find the eigenvalues of $f^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear transformation that has eigenvalues $\lambda = -1,0,2$.

> Find the eigenvalues of $f^2$.

Shouldn't the answer be like this:

- If $x$ lies in the kernel of the transformation then the eigenvalue is $0$.
- If $x$ lies in the span of the image of the transformation then the eigenvalue is $1$.

The teacher said that the eigenvalues are $1, 0, 4$.

Any insight is appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: the eigen values also get squared

Comment: Yes but doesn't $f^2$ mean that we apply the transformation once and then once again?

Comment: yes it does mean that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Pick an eigenvector $\bf v$ of $f$ of eigenvalue, say, $2$. Then, applying $f^2$ to $\bf v$ gives
$$f^2({\bf v}) = f(f{\bf v}) = f(2 {\bf v}) = 2 f({\bf v}) = 2(2 {\bf v}) = 4 {\bf v}.$$
So, what can we say about $\bf v$ with respect to $f^2$?

More generally, if the eigenvalues of a linear transformation $T: V \to V$ are $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$, what can we say about the eigenvalues of $T^2$? What about the eigenvalues of $T^k$?

Comment: That the transformation gives back vector $v$ only this time $4$ times longer???

Comment: Travis means to say that if eigen values for $f$ are $a_1,a_2..a_i$ then for $f^k$ the eigen values will be $(a_1)^k,(a_2)^k...$

Comment: @Nash Yes, and what do we call vectors that are scaled by a transformation?

Comment: Eigenvectors???

Comment: Exactly: So, $\bf v$ is a an eigenvector of $f^2$. What is its corresponding eigenvalue?

Comment: $4$ because the transformation matrix is diagonilizable (three seperate eigenvalues)  so there exists a matrix $D$ such that its diagonal is the eigenvalues and $A^k = P^-1D^kP$. Right?

Comment: Well, it's $4$ simply because $(f^2)({\bf v}) = 4 {\bf v}$. You don't need to know anything about diagonalizability or similarity to conclude this, just the fact that $\bf v$ is an eigenvector of $f$ of eigenvalue $2$.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you know that the eigenvalues are $-1,0,4$ means that you know that in a suitable basis your linear map is represented by the diagonal matrix $A=$diag$[-1,0,4]$. Therefore, since $f^2 = f\circ f$ you have that $f^2$ is represented by $A^2$, which is diagonal. Hence $f^2$ has eigenvalues $0,1,4$.

Comment: Travis has proved in general , your proof only holds true for normal operators i guess

Comment: In this case, all of the eigenvalues are distinct, so the operator is diagonalizable as rafforaffo claims.

Comment: oh missed that it was given $R^3$ sorry @rafforaffo

Comment: @Travis I still have a doubt having 3 distinct eigen values does not mean that eigen spaces are orthogonal which is necessary condition for diagonalization I guess

Comment: That's not true, unless you're restricting to diagonalization by orthogonal matrices. Are you familiar with Jordan Normal Form? In particular, its existence implies that having all distinct eigenvalues implies diagonalizability (over the algebraic closure of the underlying field, anyway).

Comment: @Travis did not know that thanks will surely look into it

Comment: You're welcome. JNF is definitely worth committing to memory, because it lets you translate most questions about abstract (finite-dimensional) linear transformations to ones about diagonal or near-diagonal matrix operators.